# Tensorflow setting layers

Tags: tensorflow, layer

I am making a Convolutional Neural Network with tensorflow. I think that all is right, but I have a problem with the shape of labels.

This is the code:

```
images, labels = images[:70], labels[:70]

# Redimensionamos las imagenes
images32 = [transform.resize(image, (28, 28), mode='reflect').astype(np.float32) for image in images]
images32 = np.array(images32)

# Input Layer
input_layer = tf.reshape(images32, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

# Convolutional Layer #1
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs=input_layer,
    filters=32,
    kernel_size=[5, 5],
    padding="same",
    activation=tf.nn.relu)

# Pooling Layer #1
pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

# Convolutional Layer #2 and Pooling Layer #2
conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs=pool1,
    filters=64,
    kernel_size=[5, 5],
    padding="same",
    activation=tf.nn.relu)
pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

# Dense Layer
pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])
dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)
dropout = tf.layers.dropout(
    inputs=dense, rate=0.4, training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

# Logits Layer
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=10)

predictions = {
    # Generate predictions (for PREDICT and EVAL mode)
    "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
    # Add `softmax_tensor` to the graph. It is used for PREDICT and by the
    # `logging_hook`.
    "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
}

if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)

# Calculate Loss (for both TRAIN and EVAL modes)
onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(labels, tf.int32), depth=10)
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(
    onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=logits)

# Configure the Training Op (for TRAIN mode)
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(
        loss=loss,
        global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

# Add evaluation metrics (for EVAL mode)
eval_metric_ops = {
    "accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(
        labels=labels, predictions=predictions["classes"])}
return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
    mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)
```

When I run it, I receive the next message:

```
ValueError: Shapes (210, 10) and (70, 10) are incompatible
```

I tried to change the labels set to 210, but then I get this other message:

```
ValueError: Shapes (900, 10) and (300, 10) are incompatible
```

I dont know what I must to change because the layers of CNN it is fine...

Some idea?

Thanks

Comment: From your question it is not clear which shapes are not compatible, nor what the exact format of your labels/images is. Perhaps try isolating the problem to a more compact/representative form.

Comment: At which line is the problem happening ? Also, try to give a smaller code with the same issue, it might help finding the problem